# Error initializing gerrit plugin project

Tags: maven, plugins, gerrit, maven-archetype

So I'm trying to follow the documented instructions in the Gerrit docs (version 2.5.2) that explain how to set up your gerrit plugin project (docs [here](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.2/dev-plugins.html)).

I started with the presentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/lucamilanesio/gerrit-how-to-cook-a-plugin-in-only-10-mins#) which worked fine until the "Step 3" slide which has a similar mvn command to what is in the gerrit doc linked above.

The project creation step fails with this error:

```
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2).
[WARNING] Use -DarchetypeRepository=<your repository> if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gerrit/gerrit-plugin-archetype/2.5-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gerrit/gerrit-plugin-archetype/2.5-SNAPSHOT/gerrit-plugin-archetype-2.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.529s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 28 09:45:15 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/361M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.google.gerrit:gerrit-plugin-archetype:2.5-SNAPSHOT) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

So I'm a little lost now.  I have no idea what to do to fix it.

Especially since I'm following the Gerrit documented command to set up the project.  I would assume this would have the correct archetype information in it.  But apparently it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Gerrit does not seem to provide their archetype on a public repo.
It looks like you will have to first build and install the archetype from the sources.

This is shown on the "Step 2" slide

Answer (score 1):

You have to clone gerrit source code and then:

```
cd gerrit/gerrit-plugin-archetype && mvn install
```

Other approach is to use the template which is mentioned in the documentation:

```
 git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/cookbook-plugin
```